# Modifying Luhn checker function to check for Laser cards

Tags: javascript

I use the following script to validate the card details entered in a form. I would like to add a function to this so that a visitor using a Laser card is alerted that we don't accept them.

The start digits of the Laser are 6304, 6706, 6771 & 6709

```
function Calculate(Luhn)
{
var sum = 0;
for (i=0; i<Luhn.length; i++ )
{
    sum += parseInt(Luhn.substring(i,i+1));
}
var delta = new Array (0,1,2,3,4,-4,-3,-2,-1,0);
for (i=Luhn.length-1; i>=0; i-=2 )
{       
    var deltaIndex = parseInt(Luhn.substring(i,i+1));
    var deltaValue = delta[deltaIndex]; 
    sum += deltaValue;
}   
var mod10 = sum % 10;
mod10 = 10 - mod10; 
if (mod10==10)
{       
    mod10=0;
}
return mod10;
}

function Validate(Luhn)
{
var LuhnDigit = parseInt(Luhn.substring(Luhn.length-1,Luhn.length));
var LuhnLess = Luhn.substring(0,Luhn.length-1);
if (Calculate(LuhnLess)==parseInt(LuhnDigit))
{
    return true;
}
alert("\n\nError with your card number! \nPlease check and correct.\n\n")   
return false;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't modify these functions to check the card type - they have a specific goal. If you change the Validate(Luhn) function so that it fails a card that passes its Luhn check but that has specific starting digits, you're making trouble for yourself later. Instead, add a new function, something like this:

```
function checkCardType(CardNumber) {
    var CardStart = CardNumber.substring(0, 4);
    if ((CardStart == '6304') || (CardStart == '6706') || (CardStart == '6771') || (CardStart == '6709')) {
        alert('We do not accept Laser cards.');
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you just keep a blacklist? You'd need to have a process to keep it up-to-date (e.g. load it from a database, manage it there - keeping it in the source is more hassle in the long term), but for such a small number of items, it would be useful:

```
function LoadBlacklist() {
   // this is the simplest example; you may want to load the array dynamically
   var bad_prefixes = [ "6304", "6706", "6771", "6709" ];
   return bad_prefixes;
}

function Validate(Luhn)
{
   var blacklist = LoadBlacklist();
   var luhn_prefix = Luhn.substring(0,4); // only check the first 4 characters
   for (var bl_pos = blacklist.length - 1; bl_pos >= 0; bl_pos--) {
       if (blacklist[bl_pos] == luhn_prefix) {
          // this card matches one of the blacklist prefixes
          return false;
       }
   }
   // if we're here, no match was found
   // go on with validation...
 }
```